# Test execution time, Visual Studio

Tags: .net, performance, visual-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing

I am trying to compare the **execution speed** of both integration tests and unit tests in my VB.net project.

I am not surprised to see unit tests taking a few milliseconds while integration tests take quite a bit more, some results are still quite surprising

[image]

Both `TestAddStudent` and `TestAddStudent2` do *exactly the same thing*, but the first one to be executed takes up to **1 sec**, whereas the second is much faster.

When I try executing the tests separately, all integration tests take about 1 sec (unit test times stay about the same).

I guess it has something to do with **initialising database**, but the initialisation should have to occur for each test so why is it taking longer on the 1st test?

I cannot really compare execution times for individual tests with these results because one of the tets takes longer for an external reason.

Do you have any idea **what is happening** and if there is something I can do to prevent it?

Comment: Change the order in which the two `TestAddStudent` tests are run, see what impact that has.

Comment: As I say it is the 1st launched that takes 1sec, if I change order then it will be TestAddStudent2 which would take 1sec

Comment: In my experience that's just the testing engine warming up. There isn't much that can be done about it. In the grand scheme of things 1 second in your integration tests will be nothing

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the majority of the time will be being taken setting up the connection to the database.  This has to be done the first time an AppDomain connects to a database.  When you're running the tests individually, this will need to be done every time, since the app domain is loaded at the beginning of each test run.

When you run all of your tests at the same time on the other hand, the first test to connect to the database takes the hit of opening the connection.  When your test is closes the database connection, rather than the connection being completely shutdown instead it is returned to the database connection pool.  When your next test runs, rather than it having to recreate the connection from scratch it simply fetches a free connection from the pool.

You haven't said which database you're using, but a summary of connection pooling for SQL server is covered [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).  If you want to force your tests to go through this hit for every test, then one option might be to call [ClearAllPools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearallpools(v=vs.110).aspx) to clear the connection pool during your test setup stage.

You said that one of your goals is to compare the execution speed of integration tests and unit tests.  This database connection setup time is part of integration testing, however if your goal is to compare individual tests (AddStudent, AddStudent2, ModifyStudent) and you want to remove this anomaly from the tests you care about then one approach would be to create a test simply to establish the database connection and initialise the pool.

You haven't said which test framework you're using, however NUnit for example runs tests in alphabetical order.  So if you created a class `AAAAAIntegrationInitialiser` with a test `AAAAAInitialiseDatabase` that accessed the database somehow, it would be run first and you could ignore this test's time.

However, you're still likely to find anomalies in the timings that will vary from run to run, and may well vary if you were to run the tests in a different order.  If you're repeatedly hitting a particular table, then your database is likely to hold more information from that table in memory and so have it more readily available for fetching etc.